# Custom results width in RMarkdown

Tags: r, layout, r-markdown

I am creating an RMarkdown presentation and would like to set a custom width for the results. For example, when I use the code

````
---
title: 'Example presentation'
output: html_document
--- 
  
# Summarize data

```{r}
data(mtcars)
summary(mtcars)
```
````

The results display ~67 characters characters per line:

```
##       mpg             cyl             disp             hp       
##  Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0  
##  1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5  
##  Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0  
##  Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7  
##  3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0  
##  Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0  
##       drat             wt             qsec             vs        
##  Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513   Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000  
##  1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581   1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000  
##  Median :3.695   Median :3.325   Median :17.71   Median :0.0000  
##  Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217   Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375  
##  3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610   3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
##  Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424   Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000  
##        am              gear            carb      
##  Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
##  1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
##  Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
##  Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
##  3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
##  Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```

Is there a way to set a custom line width, so the results fit better to the width of my presentation? For example, are there chunk options that would allow me to show this instead?

```
##       mpg             cyl             disp             hp            drat             wt      
##  Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513  
##  1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5   1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581   
##  Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0   Median :3.695   Median :3.325   
##  Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7   Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217   
##  3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0   3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610   
##  Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424
##       qsec             vs              am              gear            carb      
##  Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000  Min.   :0.0000  Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
##  1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000  1st Qu.:0.0000  1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
##  Median :17.71   Median :0.0000  Median :0.0000  Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
##  Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375  Mean   :0.4062  Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
##  3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000  3rd Qu.:1.0000  3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
##  Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000  Max.   :1.0000  Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```

Comment: Try `options(width=99)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
---
title: 'Example presentation'
output: html_document
--- 
  
# Summarize data   
```{r}
options(width = 100)
data(mtcars)
summary(mtcars)
```
````

Does exactly what you want

Comment: please review your answer [edit] and update it so that everyone will understand its meaning